# Server.MapPath equivalence in php

Tags: php

Server.MapPath is used in asp to reveal real path to a server or directory.

Does anyone know the equivalence in php?

I have a folder called pdfdownloads which is inside another folder called Boards.

Full path looks like:

c:\inetpub\wwwroo\Staging\Boards

Then pdfdownloads and rest of my php files are inside Boards.

Rather than specify this path, I would like to use the equivalence of server.mapPath() to reveal them.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Look at `realpath` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by bobdye, `realpath` will resolve and returns the full path.

You can also use `__DIR__`, its a magic constant that will return the full path of the current file that is being executed.

For example, if you have a file index.php in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Staging\Boards\`, you could do the following :

```
<?php

echo __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'pdfdownloads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

It will output :

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Staging\Boards\pdfdownloads\
```

Using the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` will let the PHP engine take care of using the right directory separator (`\` or `/`) depending on the OS.